# Azure storage forgetting password after reboot

Tags: azure, azure-storage, net-use

I'm connecting a Azure store to Windows 10 computer with the following commmands

```
cmdkey /add:acc_name.file.core.windows.net /user:AZURE\acc_name /pass:acc_store_key
net use z: \\acc_name.file.core.windows.net\resource /u:AZURE\acc_name acc_store_key
```

if i run

```
cmdkey /list
```

it looks like it adds the key properly as i get

```
Target: Domain:target=acc_name.file.core.windows.net
Type: Domain Password
User: AZURE\acc_name
```

And the network mount is mounted properly by net use.

However after a reboot i get asked again for the password to the network share.

Comment: Have you tried `net use` with `/PERSISTENT:YES`?

Comment: Yes, and it does not work.